# Why do I get NaN p values in some variables when using mgcv to fit generalized additive mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, computational-statistics, mgcv

I am currently trying to fit milk production data collected for three years by using generalized additive mixed model through mgcv package. The problem is, I am getting NaN p values in some variables. However, when fitting the same data using R-INLA I do get results for all variables.

Is there any thing I can do so that I can fix the NaN p value issue? Is it okay to go ahead and interpret the coefficient with NaN p values as insignificant since I have used the model for prediction and it provided reasonable results.

```
Formula:
Milk_production ~ s(Total_cost_feeding, bs = "cr") + s(Area_owned, 
    bs = "cr") + s(Total_cost_veterinary_services, bs = "cr") + 
    s(Total_cost_labour, bs = "cr") + s(Total_cost_water, bs = "cr") + 
    s(Number_cattle, bs = "cr") + Feed_purchases + Use_vaccination + 
    Use_dewormer + Use_tick_treatment + Hiring_labour + Water_purchases + 
    Practiced_mating + Major_feeding_practices + Person_admin_vaccine + 
    Person_admin_dewormer + AvgFreq_watering + NewMain_housing_syst + 
    Main_Mating + Person_admin_tick_treatment + Main_source_water + 
    s(year, bs = "re") + s(id, bs = "re")


gam.check(MilkGAMMA3)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 11 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.0003661713,0.001213692]
(score 2552.286 & scale 0.372274).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [0.0003158684,642.9963].
Model rank =  1074 / 1077 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                                      k'    edf k-index p-value
s(Total_cost_feeding)               9.00   1.34    0.95    0.28
s(Area_owned)                       9.00   1.00    0.99    0.76
s(Total_cost_veterinary_services)   9.00   3.47    1.01    0.91
s(Total_cost_labour)                9.00   1.61    0.96    0.40
s(Total_cost_water)                 9.00   1.00    0.96    0.36
s(Number_cattle)                    9.00   4.10    1.01    0.94
s(year)                             3.00   1.13      NA      NA
s(id)                             995.00 228.20      NA      NA


summary(MilkGAMMA3)
Parametric coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   1.6597523  0.1927798   8.610  < 2e-16 ***
Feed_purchases2              -0.1660057  0.0723846  -2.293   0.0221 *  
Use_vaccination2              0.1244081  0.0862886   1.442   0.1497    
Use_vaccination3             -0.0540667  0.0518530  -1.043   0.2974    
Use_dewormer2                 0.0494045  0.0789549   0.626   0.5317    
Use_dewormer3                 0.0000000  0.0000000     NaN      NaN   
Use_tick_treatment2          -0.1386099  0.1072616  -1.292   0.1966    
Use_tick_treatment3           0.0000000  0.0000000     NaN      NaN   
Hiring_labour2               -0.1851812  0.0884336  -2.094   0.0365 *  
Water_purchases2             -0.0542968  0.1122727  -0.484   0.6288    
Practiced_mating2            -0.0596619  0.0805403  -0.741   0.4590    
Major_feeding_practices2      0.5181813  0.0807371   6.418 2.26e-10 ***
Person_admin_vaccine2         0.0037259  0.0659497   0.056   0.9550    
Person_admin_vaccine3         0.0000000  0.0000000     NaN      NaN   
Person_admin_dewormer2        0.0402061  0.0629497   0.639   0.5232    
Person_admin_dewormer3        0.0345815  0.0591983   0.584   0.5593    
AvgFreq_watering2             0.0991666  0.0490348   2.022   0.0434 *  
AvgFreq_watering3            -0.0007869  0.2048929  -0.004   0.9969    
NewMain_housing_syst2        -0.1346713  0.0819062  -1.644   0.1005    
NewMain_housing_syst3        -0.2953771  0.1794867  -1.646   0.1002    
Main_Mating2                 -0.0804600  0.0843822  -0.954   0.3406    
Main_Mating3                  0.3494567  0.1621204   2.156   0.0314 *  
Person_admin_tick_treatment2  0.0308237  0.0772629   0.399   0.6900    
Person_admin_tick_treatment3 -0.0746526  0.0620250  -1.204   0.2291    
Main_source_water2            0.0271432  0.0568202   0.478   0.6330    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                      edf  Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(Total_cost_feeding)               1.344   1.541  2.140   0.0861 .  
s(Area_owned)                       1.001   1.001  0.002   0.9714    
s(Total_cost_veterinary_services)   3.467   3.822  6.593 4.81e-05 ***
s(Total_cost_labour)                1.614   1.905  0.890   0.4808    
s(Total_cost_water)                 1.003   1.005  0.033   0.8631    
s(Number_cattle)                    4.096   4.687 42.936  < 2e-16 ***
s(year)                             1.126   2.000  1.631   0.1060    
s(id)                             228.203 994.000  0.296 7.02e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 1074/1077
R-sq.(adj) =  0.487   Deviance explained = 59.9%
-REML = 2552.3  Scale est. = 0.37227   n = 1139
```

Comment: It looks to me like either use_dewormer 3 and Person_admin_vaccine_3 only take on one value (in which case they are collinear with the intercept) or perhaps are collinear with other variables.  If you drop them from the regression and the "deviance explained" doesn't change, that would support these hypotheses.

Comment: What @jbowman said, but also, the estimated coefficients for the terms with `NaN` are all zero, so what's to interpret? Does INLA return different estimated values for those coefficients??